# Ionic/Angular http.post will be called more than one time

Tags: angular, rest, http, post, ionic-framework

I using Ionic3 and Angular 5 and try to send json data from client to server over http.post.

But from unknown reason, when I send the post request manually per button click, the post request will be called automatically every some minutes... But I dont want that. The client should send ONLY ONE post request.

Please can anybody explain what the problem is?

----My Calling class

```
import { ConnectionServiceProvider } from '../../providers/connection-service/connection-service';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
 selector: 'page-result-modal',
 templateUrl: 'result-modal.html',
 })

sendGameResults() {
 this.serverConnection.sendGameResult(result).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(result);
  }, error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
 }
}
```

----My ConnectionService

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ConnectionServiceProvider {
mainUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8080";

constructor(public http: HttpClient) {}

sendGameResult(result) {
  var data = JSON.stringify(result);
  return this.http.post(this.mainUrl + '/sendgameresult', data, { headers: { 
     'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }).map(response => {
        return response;
  });
}
```

----- HTML

```
<ion-row nowrap no-padding>
        <button class="send-game-results" (click)="sendGameResults()" ion- 
    button full>Senden</button>
</ion-row>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add the full calling class and HTML template please? Need to see how that block of code is being called

Comment: Hi, I've added the relevant informations. The whole html and class is to large to post it complete.But I dont use any other provider or http post there.

Comment: I've noticed a couple of typos, such as the service function being called `sendGameResult`, and you try to call `this.serverConnection.sendResult` but I'm not able to reproduce the problem. Can you create a StackBlitz reproduction please?

Comment: Sorry that was a copy&paste issue. What do you mean with StackBlitz?

Comment: StackBlitz is a website that allows you to run Ionic code. When I added the code from above, I couldn't reproduce the issue. Are you able to create one that reproduces the issue, save it, and share the URL? https://stackblitz.com/fork/ionic

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure , but you also can create a variable, and call this variable if you will get success for example:

public canelReq = this.yourService.unsubscribe();

And then when you get success just call this method

```
succsess => this.cancelReq();
```